# {“success”:true} but fineuploader shows error but uploads the file properly

Tags: php, jquery, html

The php server script returns {"success":true}, and upload the file correctly, but in the webpage, it shows that there was an error uploading in red.

On Checking the console for the same i got this

fineuploader-3.2.min.js:

> [FineUploader] Error when attempting to parse xhr response text
>   (SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1)

```
<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Undefined property: stdClass::$relation_value</p>
<p>Filename: libraries/Image_crud.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 527</p>


    <p>Backtrace:</p>
    <p style="margin-left:10px">
            File: /storage/ssd2/410/2722410/public_html/application/libraries/Image_crud.php<br />
            Line: 527<br />
            Function: _error_handler            </p>

            <p style="margin-left:10px">
            File: /storage/ssd2/410/2722410/public_html/application/controllers/<-COntroller name->.php<br />
            Line: 56<br />
            Function: render            </p>


            <p style="margin-left:10px">
            File: /storage/ssd2/410/2722410/public_html/index.php<br />
            Line: 315<br />
            Function: require_once          </p>
</div>{"success":true}
```

**

> Please help me guys i am really in trouble

**
P:S It is working fine in my **local (Windows 10)** chrome ,FF on wamp server but when i **uploaded in free hosting service** i got the above error while uploading
this is not duplicate question

Comment: is it related to magento?

Comment: yes, somehow i can say that i am using a fineuploader in my project for uploading images, docs when i tried in local all is fine but when i tried on client's server the image, documnet upload without any problem but the progress bar show upload failed and in console i get the mentioned error